# Site "chat with an expert" script?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

While browsing the question on low character HP this morning a little black box popped in on the right-lower corner of my screen. It offered me the option of chatting with an expert, not now and never.

Curious I clicked to chat. It came up CSS style with a small chat box where the "expert" asked if I had any questions about low character HP. The picture wasn't anyone I recognized from the site anyway and I've been around fairly often.

WTH is this? Something on the server side or on mine? I didn't find anything through searching.

Comment: Check the date.

Comment: @C.Ross If it's an April Fool's joke, it's a not a very obvious one, nor is it clear why it's supposed to be funny. Is it some kind of reference to a feature of some other Q&A site?

Comment: Playing with it a bit, it appears to be an Eliza-like bot. I suppose that's a bit funny, but it's not April Fool's-funny so much as haha-Eliza-is-dumb funny, which is true every day of the year.

Comment: @C.Ross interestingly that didn't even cross my mind.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie It does and it is. Eliza was (is) a really funny experiment - as long as that's all this is lol. No longer as concerned about my PC and browser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an SE-wide April Fools joke.  Yes, a bit of a blah one. See [What is "chat with an expert"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174407/what-is-chat-with-an-expert) for more on that.

Comment: Got it, thank you for the question link.